# Transferring Files from an Azure VM to a Google Cloud VM is Very Slow

Tags: performance, file, transfer

I have some files on an Azure VM that I want to transfer to a new Google Cloud VM, but attempts so far have proved to be very slow. I have logged into the Google VM (Windows Server 2016) using RDP, and from there to the Azure VM (Windows 2012) using RDP, exposing a Google disk to the session. The Google disk is a 2Tb SSD. When I try to copy a set of files it tells me the transfer rate is around 10Mbps.

The Azure VM has an upload capability approaching 1000Mbps, whereas the Google VM has a download speed of 87Mbps. Even though the Google speed is a factor of 10 slower than Azure, I would still expect better transfer speeds than 10Mbps.

Could anyone suggest why it is so slow, and/or how to improve it?

Perhaps I have been naïve in my technique, so if there is a better way please let me know.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Charles

Comment: hi ckl, I wonder what kind of files are you trying to move. If you are trying move a file of 1 GB (for example) is much different from copying 1.000.000 files of 1 KB. 
Often, best option is to compress into bigger files before move

Comment: Hi Maurizio, the files are large (SQL Server .bak files). Some are 50Gb and more.

Comment: Do you have an MPLS,point to point connection between the 2 machines? I don't think so (usually not) and therefore you are going best effort on the internet channells. There are so many factors that could impact, the firewalls (MS and Google), local SW, internet congestion, the continent of the datacenter, performance throttling imposed by the provider for such a traffic. It is very hard to say. 

Besides, do you have a local antivirus on both machines?

I don't believe there is much you can do about it.

Comment: It would be depressing to think that this is the best it gets, but if that's the case then so be it. Thanks.